# Program on Named pipe

Tags: c, unix, pipe, named

Here is my logic: I am using a bank management program in which when an account is created it will display in other side "Account created" and its necessary details.
then in main file if deposit it should show deposited amount and current balance in other side

The problem with me is that I can only do one at a time, I want to check whether it is deposit or create and do the operation for both

Heres my code:

PROGRAM : a.c

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void deposit();
int fd,fd1;
char * myfifo = "myfifo";
char * myfifo1 = "myfifo1";
int accno;
char name[15];
int balance;

void create();

int main()
{
    int ch;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n*********************");
        printf("\n BANKING ");
        printf("\n*********************");
        printf("\n1-Creation"); 
        printf("\n2-Deposit");
        printf("\n3-Exit");
        printf("\nEnter your choice");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1: create();
            break;
            case 2: deposit();
            break;
            case 3: exit(0);
            break;
            default: printf("Enter 1-3 only");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void create(){
    fd1 = open("bank.txt", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY);

    printf("\nEnter The Account Number\n");
    scanf("%d",&accno);
    write(fd1,&accno,sizeof(accno));
    printf("\nAccount:%d",accno);
    printf("\nEnter The Name\n");
    scanf("%s",&name);
    write(fd1,&name,sizeof(name));
    printf("\nName:%s",name);
    printf("\nEnter The Balance\n");
    scanf("%d",&balance);
    write(fd1,&balance,sizeof(balance));
    printf("\nBalance Available:%d",balance);

    close(fd1);

    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);
    fd1 = open("bank.txt",O_RDONLY);

    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);

    read(fd1,&accno,sizeof(accno));
    write(fd,&accno,sizeof(accno));
    printf("\nAccount:%d",accno);
    read(fd1,&name,sizeof(name));
    write(fd,&name,sizeof(name));
    printf("\nName:%s",name);
    read(fd1,&balance,sizeof(balance));
    write(fd,&balance,sizeof(balance));
    printf("\nBalance Available:%d",balance);

    close(fd);
    close(fd1);

    /* remove the FIFO */
    unlink(myfifo);
}

void deposit()
{
    int i=5, acc,b=0,m=0,n=8;
    float aa;
    fd1 = open("bank.txt", O_RDWR);

    printf("\n*************************************");
    printf("\n DEPOSIT ");
    printf("\n*************************************");
    printf("\nEnter your Account Number");
    scanf("%d",&acc);
    for(b=0;b<i;b++)
    {
        if(accno == acc)
        m = n; 
    }

    if(accno == acc){
        printf("\n Account Number : %d",accno);
        printf("\n Name : %s",name);
        printf("\n Deposit : %d",balance);
        printf("\n How Much Deposited Now:");
        scanf("%f",&aa);
        balance=balance+aa;
        write(fd1,&balance,sizeof(balance));                                                                                                                                                                     
        printf("\nDeposit Amount is :%f",balance);

        mkfifo(myfifo1, 0666);

        fd = open(myfifo1, O_WRONLY);                                                                                                                                                                                      
        read(fd1,&balance,sizeof(balance));
        write(fd,&balance,sizeof(balance));
        printf("\nBalance Available:%d",balance);
        close(fd);
        close(fd1);
        unlink(myfifo1);
    }
    else
    {                                                                                                                                      
        printf("\nACCOUNT NUMBER IS INVALID");                                                                                                                                                                                
    }
}
```

PROGRAM: b.c

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_BUF 1024

int main()
{
    int fd,fd1;
    char * myfifo = "myfifo";
    char * myfifo1 = "myfifo1";                                                                                                                                                                                
    int accno;
    char name[15];
    int balance;
    /* open, read, and display the message from the FIFO */
    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);

    printf("Account Created\n----------------\n");

    read(fd,&accno,sizeof(accno));
    printf("Account Number: %d\n", accno);

    read(fd,&name,sizeof(name));
    printf("Name: %s\n", name);

    read(fd,&balance,sizeof(balance));
    printf("Balance: %d\n", balance);

    close(fd);                                                                                                                                                                                  
    fd1 = open(myfifo1, O_RDONLY);                                                                                                                                                                                 
    printf("Deposited\n----------------\n");
    read(fd1,&balance,sizeof(balance));
    printf("Balance: %d\n", balance);                                                                                                                                                                                
    close(fd1);
}
```

Here in the program file b.c I want to check which one is executing now and to continue only that i.e   if deposit is chosen in program a.c then only deposited should display in prog b.c

Comment: TL;DR! Please narrow down the code to the parts you have problems with, or better yet create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.